# Return whole string if it cannot be split using substr / instr

Tags: oracle

My data looks like this

```
READINGS
----------
100 - Hot
200 - Cold
300 - Warm
80
8989970
```

I need to return just the first part of each line like so

```
READINGS
----------
100
200
300
80
8989970
```

I've tried the following

```
SUBSTR(READINGS,0,instr(READINGS,' - ')-1)
```

But if the instr() failes to find ' - ' the field ends up null like so

```
READINGS
----------
100 - Hot
200 - Cold
300 - Warm
null
null
```

Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Aramillo's answer will have better performance than a regexp, yet you could do something like this, `regexp_substr( '100 ', '^\d*',1,1 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case. Something like:

```
CASE WHEN instr(READINGS,' - ') = 0 THEN READINGS 
ELSE SUBSTR(READINGS,0,instr(READINGS,' - ')-1) END
```

Comment: Why would the 2nd parameter of `SUBSTR()` be `0`? Oracle will just treat it as `1`.

Comment: Yes @DavidFaber , you are right, i usually use 1, but OP is using 0, and it's working right too.:)